# Restsharp returns 403 while Postman returns 200

Tags: c#, httpclient, restsharp, wp-api

This is the (modified) snippet that Postman gives for successful call to my page.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://sub.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic anVyYTp3MmZacmo2eGtBOHJsRWrt");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

But when placed in my c# app it returns 403 forbidden, while Postman makes it and recieves 200.
The same thing happens when I use httpclient in my app (403).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`RestClient.Authenticator`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Authenticators) instead:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://sub.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me")
{ 
      Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("User", "Pass")
};

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

**Edit:**

Since the issue (as mentioned in the comments) is the fact that `RestSharp` doesn't flow the authentication through redirects, I'd suggest going with a combination of `HttpClient` with a `HttpClientHandler` where you set the authentication to flow.

Comment: Same thing happens, I get 403 forbidden.

Comment: I'm copy pasting between Postman and my app, and the base64 representation of username:password in Basic header is the same.

Comment: It seems the api url, upon successful auth, immediately 302 redirects to another url in the same subdir, but basic auth header doesn't move along with the redirect.
There is a post with an example of creating a custom authenticator, but I could not get it to work in my case.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195208/restsharp-authenticator-follow-302-redirect

I was wondering if there's a way to tell if there was a successful auth on first api url, then capture the redirected url and try the same auth on that. Not clean but could work with that.

Comment: @vani Have you tried using `HttpClient` instead? I'd suggest using it with `HttpClientHandler`.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll go with that route (httpclient), I'll take a httpstatus.found (302) as a successful login with basic authentication on first url, anything else returned will be considered as rejection. How can I mark your comment as correct answer here at StackO?

Comment: @vani I've edited my answer to include what I've said in the comments. If you wish, you can mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**[Solution]**
Use the below line for the header

Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");